# Analytic Functions on Upper Half Plane Satisfying Inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Original Problem.** Let $\mathbb{H}=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C} : \Im(z)>0\right\}$ be the open upper half plane. Determine all analytic functions $f:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ that satisfy the inequality
>
> $$\left|f(z)\right|\leq\Im(z) \tag{1}$$

This is an old qual problem which I at first found deceptively simple and asked for a fresh set of eyes. The solution is straightforward. The inequality implies $f$ has a continuous extension $\tilde{f}:\overline{\mathbb{H}}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ to the closed upper half plane by setting $\tilde{f}(x):=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. By Schwarz reflection, we obtain an entire function $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ which vanishes on the real axis. By the identity theorem, $\tilde{f}\equiv 0$, implying $f\equiv 0$.

I tried coming up with another solution, for example using maximum modulus principle, but didn't get anywhere. So if anyone has a different proof, I would be interested in seeing it.

At the suggestion of David C. Ullrich, we consider the problem of determining harmonic functions in the upper half plane satisfying the same inequality.

> **Problem.** With $\mathbb{H}$ as above, determine all harmonic functions $f:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. $\Delta f=0$) that satisfy the inequality in (1).

An answer to this problem has been posted below.

Comment: It is that simple.

Comment: Ok, that's too easy, now find all the real-valued harmonic functions in the upper half-plane satisfying the same inequality...

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is fine. (Answered to keep the question off the unanswered list.)

Answer (score 0):

Any harmonic function $u$ in the upper half space $\mathbb{H}^{+}\simeq\mathbb{R}_{+}^{2}$ which extends to a continuous function on $\overline{H^{+}}$, vanishing on the real line, extends to a harmonic function on the whole plane by Schwarz reflection. If such $u$ grows at most polynomially in bounded, then it defines a tempered distribution in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{2})$.

We make use of the following two results. A proof of the first one can be found in [L. Grafakos, Classical Fourier Analysis, Third Edition, Proposition 2.4.1], and the second is elementary.

> **Theorem.** Let $u\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ be a tempered distribution. If $u$ is supported in the set $\left\{x\right\}$, then
>   \begin{align*}
> u=\sum_{\left|\alpha\right|\leq k}c_{\alpha}\partial^{\alpha}\delta_{x}
> \end{align*}
>   for some nonnegative integer $k$, where $c_{\alpha}\in\mathbb{C}$.

and under the Fourier transform convention

$$\widehat{\phi}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\phi(x)e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi}\mathrm{d}x, \qquad\forall \xi\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$$

> **Lemma.** If $u=(-2\pi i x)^{\alpha}$, then $\widehat{u}=(-1)^{\left|\alpha\right|}\partial^{\alpha}\delta$.

Taking inverse Fourier transforms, we conclude that the harmonic function $u$ must be of the form
\begin{align*}
u(x,y)=\sum_{\left|\alpha\right|\leq k}c_{\alpha}(2\pi i xy)^{\alpha}
\end{align*}
for some integer $k$. The condition that $\left|u(x,y)\right|\leq\left|y\right|$ forces $c_{\alpha}=0\Leftrightarrow \alpha=(0,1)$ and for such $\alpha$, $\left|c_{\alpha}(2\pi i )\right|=1$. We conclude that $u(x,y)=e^{i\theta}y$, for some fixed $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$. If we require $u$ to be real-valued, then $u(x,y)=y$.